# Add another button beside "Refund" button in WooCommerce admin orders

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce, backend, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a new button for other actions beside the refund button in Edit Order page for WooCommerce.

I know it may be possible by hooks, but I can't seem to find the right hook to execute for it.

Comment: This is the hook you are looking for: [woocommerce_order_item_add_action_buttons](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-items.php#L287)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following *(where you will replace "custom" by your desired action slug and name)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_add_action_buttons', 'wc_order_item_add_action_buttons_callback', 10, 1 );
function wc_order_item_add_action_buttons_callback( $order ) {
    $label = esc_html__( 'Custom', 'woocommerce' );
    $slug  = 'custom';
    ?>
    <button type="button" class="button <?php echo $slug; ?>-items"><?php echo $label; ?></button>
    <?php
}
```

The hook is located in [`includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-items.php` (line 288)](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-items.php#L288)

Then you will have to enable Ajax for this button, adding some jQuery code (sender) and some PHP code *(WordPress Admin Ajax receiver)*, just like for [`WC_Ajax`  `refund_line_items()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.2/includes/class-wc-ajax.php#L1830-L1914)…

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!